# Удаление лог файлов при входе в систему

Tags: linux, shell

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При входе в систему хочу удалять некоторые лог файлы но нечего не происходит.
Создал баш скрипт :

```
#!/bin/bash 
#clean log files


if [ -e /var/log/syslog ]
then
    sudo rm /var/log/syslog
fi

if [ -e /var/log/kern.log ]
then
    sudo rm /var/log/kern.log
fi

if [ -e /var/log/dpkg.log ]
then
    sudo rm /var/log/dpkg.log
fi
```

Затем в директории ~/.config/upstart создал .conf файл

```
description     "my job"
start on startup
task
exec /home/spock/Desktop/bash_scr/log_clean.sh
```

Comment: а кто запускает файл upstart ? это от какой подсистемы ? И удалять логи подобным образом не хорошо, во первых место на диске это не освободит, во вторых все новые сообщения продолжат писаться в удаленные файлы и в третьих, зачем их удалять именно при входе, так вы никогда не узнаете о проблемах в системе

Comment: я использую ubunu 16.04. Некоторые лог файлы все таки очень тяжелы.

Comment: тогда смотрите в сторону logrotate, он по скрону периодически архивирует старые логи и удаляет совсем старые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте файл с вашим кодом, но без использования `sudo` в коде, в `/etc/cron.daily/purgelogs`, дайте ему права на выполнение и готово:

```
chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/purgelogs
```

Лучшим вариантом было бы использовать logrotate. Устанавливаете и все, настраивать не нужно:

```
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```